# What's the point of free functions?

Tags: c++, oop

I heard about functions that were with classes, but outside classes. I mean, these are useful for the class implementation because it uses it, but it's not in the class body, it's outside, lost in nowhere.
So, I was wondering, what's the point of writing a free function instead of just writing a member function ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What should, say, `std::malloc` be a member of in your imagined better parallel universe, and how would that improve software design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Free functions offer far better decoupling and clarity of interfaces. When most of your algorithmic logic is provided by free functions, your data structures need to have clear purposes and appropriate interfaces. The result is code that minimizes coupling, which is easier to reason about, to test and to depend on.

Generally, data structures should be as small as possible and as big as necessary to fulfil one single, specific purpose; data structures should be combined via composition, and logic should be provided by free functions that accesses the data's public interfaces as much as possible.

Member functions may be convenient, and of course it is necessary to have *some* member functions to provide the aforementioned interface, but it's a slippery slope, and when done wrong you end up with something like `std::string`.

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your message :o

Comment: @FeelZoR `std::string` is the zombie apocalypse regarding it's final interface and avoidance of state cluttering.

Comment: Does it mean we should avoid it and prefer a char array?

Comment: @FeelZoR: The interface of `std::string` is the result of your proposed kind of thinking, and it is *far* too large and specific. Note that it duplicates a large part of `<algorithm>`. A string class could be very light and simple, and all interesting operations could be provided as generic algorithms that are useful even outside of the context of strings.

Comment: @FeelZoR: Take [std::string:find_first_not_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) as an example. It has no business being a member of `std::string`. It could be implemented as a free function, because it only operates on `std::string`'s public interface. It does not need access to `std::string`'s internals. As a free function this would be immediately clear, and when it comes time to analyze an issue, it is that type of decoupling, that makes the job so much easier.

Comment: @FeelZoR: Also, we wouldn't have had to duplicate the entire 200+ functions into `std::string_view`...

Answer (score 2):

If a function does not need to keep state there's no reason to make it part of a class.
Consider

```
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

The function does its job fine on its own, it has no need for a class object.

Comment: Mmh, okay, thanks, I see ^^